# Export HTML using dark theme?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to export an org file to HTML, it also uses `htmlize.el` to highlight source code, but the HTML overall theme uses white background - can I somehow cause it to use a dark theme?

Even if I can only set the background for code blocks - that would do just fine too.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `htmlize` uses your buffer color theme to generate its HTML. If you change the background color using `set-background-color`, then run `htmlize-buffer`, your newly specified color should be represented in the result.